# Matplotlib figsize behaving strange in WXAgg

Tags: python, matplotlib

Im trying to resize a figure to A4 paper size to save it as pdf. This gives strange behavior when using WXAgg. Here is an example:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use("WXAgg")
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# data to plot
x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.005)
y = np.sin(x)

# plot the data
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
ax.plot(x, y)

# resize figure and immediatly print it's size
page_width, page_height = (8.2765, 11.70475) #A4
fig.set_size_inches(page_width, page_height)
print fig.get_size_inches()
```

The output I get is `[ 8.27  7.59]`, not as expected. When I comment out the `mpl.use("WXAgg")`, it works fine. The output then is `[  8.2765   11.70475]` as expected.

EDIT: Apparently this has something to do with the size of the screen. I changed screens (plugged in a monitor to my laptop) and the output changed to `[ 8.27  9.39]`

What is happening here? And how do I get the right figure size with WXAgg?

Some information about my system:

- OS: macOS High Sierra `10.13.1`
- python: `2.7.13`
- Matplotlib: `2.2.3`

Comment: Can you try `fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8.2765, 11.70475))` and comment out the second last and third last line? For me your code works fine and prints the correct dimensions

Comment: @Bazingaa That does give the expected output. However, I need to change the figure size after creation. Strange that you don't get the same results...

Comment: If two people run the same code and get different results it might be a versioning issue. Which version of matplotlib are you using?

Comment: The one I tried on was `2.0.2`

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I added the info about versions to the post.

Comment: I do not have WX to test. I wonder if `7.59` might be correlated to the screen resolution (i.e. the figure is shrunk as to fit the screen).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest You are right! I coincidentally changed screens and the output changed, again the width is correct (or rounded) and the height is incorrect. More confused now...

Comment: ...but still only with WX?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Yes. Without WXagg it works fine on any screen. The screen then has no influence (as it should when I set the figsize).

Comment: How do you run the code? Is it as script or from within some IDE? Also, if you save the figure via `plt.savefig()`, does it have the expected size or not?

Comment: For debugging one would want to find out  if [this line](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/ee8e2ad35eb1ca79e27da09f055fcc7e73d72855/lib/matplotlib/figure.py#L911) ever gets called, e.g. by putting a print statement into the `if` clause.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I ran it from IDLE, but from console gives same result. When saving the fig, the size is the reported figsize (not A4) and not the figsize that I set.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest yes that line does get called

Comment: Not having WX for testing available, I think I cannot assist further. But you may report this at the [issue tracker](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues).